# using a temporary table with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, t-sql, temp-tables, sql-function

I'm trying to make what seems to be an advanced use of NHibernate with sql server functions.

I'm using NHibernate's ICriteria interface to supply paging, sorting and filtering for my listviews.
one of business objects is an aggregation of items from 3 different tables.
in order to do this aggregation in the DB I've used a transact-sql function, accepting parameters.
I'm using the IQuery interface returned by session.GetNamedQuery to invoke the function. but in order to use the paging/filtering/sorting code i'd like to use the ICriteria interface.
in order to achieve that I considered:

1. Opening a new transaction
2. calling the function which will create a global temporary table (instead of returning the result as it does now)
3. somehow alter the NHibernate mapping so it applies for the temporary table (not sure I can do that, also this has to be specific to the scope where I create the transaction...)
4. run the query on the new table using the new mapping, using the ICriteria interface
5. Delete the temporary table

so a number of questions:

1. can you suggest an alternative?
2. is it possible to replace the table in an NHibernate mapping on run time, locally for a specific code scope?
3. how costly would it be to generate and dispose of the temporary table?

Comment: I cannot suggest an alternative when I don't know where to suggest the alternative for. What are the classes, what are the tables? It sound strange to use a temp table for what you describe, but maybe it's logical in the context you use it?

Comment: I agree with Paco, I don't see the need for a temp table..

Answer (score 1):

Can you replace the function with a view? This view could aggregate the 3 tables, be mapped by NHibernate, and easily paged/sorted/filtered.

Comment: I could do that but it would hurt performance, since the join will be performed on all rows in the 3 tables, vs. the join I use in the function which is done for a specific foreign key. I hope to get around to supply more info soon, as suggested by @Paco, pardon my latency... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post which shows how you can do exactly this here: [pagination for performance intensive queries using nhibernate and sql server temporary tables](http://minhajuddin.com/2011/02/11/-pagination-for-performance-intensive-queries-using-nhibernate-and-sql-server-temporary-tables/)

Answer (score 0):

**I use a table variable inside of an Hibernate SQL query using SQL 2012 Dialect, like below.**
For my scenario I couldn't get a particular parameterized, paginated query to work in under 17 seconds no matter how I constructed the filter. By using a table variable, the time to grab page N with a page size of 1000 resulted in sub-second response.

All the magic happens in the SQL below that

1. **creates a table variable** - `declare @temporderstatus table`
2. **selects the rows into the table variable** - `insert into @temporderstatus` filtered by the sql in *sqlfilter* string
3. **selects the data from the table variable to return to NHibernate** ordered so that pagination returns a predictable result set - `select OrderNum, Customer... from @temporderstatus ORDER BY StatusCodeChangedDate, OrderNum`
4. **uses the NHibernate paging functions** to insert the necessary *ROW/OFFSET* statements using SQL Server 2012 dialect - `SetFirstResult((pagination.Page - 1) * pagination.PageSize).SetMaxResults( pagination.PageSize )`

Unlike a temp table, a table variable cleans up after itself, so it is ideal for NHibernate scenarios where you have a web server that is serving paginated requests.

Here is my code...

```
            var session = _sessionManager.GetStatelessSession();
            StringBuilder sqlfilter = new StringBuilder(
                @"FROM Orders o join OrderType ot ON o.OrderType = ot.OrderType where o.StatusDate between :fromDate and :toDate" );
            var mainQuery = session.CreateSQLQuery(
                $@"declare @temporderstatus table (OrderNum int not null, CustomerID int,  OrderType varchar(16), Status varchar(3), StatusCodeChangedDate datetime, OrderDate datetime, DeliveryDate datetime)
      insert into @temporderstatus
      SELECT o.OrderNum, o.CustomerID, ot.Description AS OrderType, o.StatusCode AS Status, o.StatusCodeChangedDate, o.OrderDate, o.DeliveryDate 
      {sqlfilter}
      select OrderNum, CustomerID, OrderType, Status, StatusCodeChangedDate, OrderDate, DeliveryDate 
      from @temporderstatus  
      ORDER BY StatusCodeChangedDate, OrderNum 
      ");

       //construct the count query
       var totalCountQuery = session.CreateSQLQuery($"SELECT COUNT(1) OCount {sqlfilter} ");
            totalCountQuery.AddScalar("OCount", NHibernateUtil.Int32);
            totalCountQuery.SetParameter("fromDate", criteria.fromDate);
            totalCountQuery.SetParameter("toDate", criteria.toDate);
            var totalCountResults = totalCountQuery.UniqueResult<int>();
            pagination.TotalResultCount = totalCountResults;
            if (pagination.TotalResultCount == 0)
            {
                //no results so don't waste time doing another query
                return new List<OrderDataDto>();
            }

       //finish constructing the main query
            mainQuery.AddEntity(typeof(OrderDataDto));
            mainQuery.SetParameter("fromDate", criteria.fromDate);
            mainQuery.SetParameter("toDate", criteria.toDate);
            var mainQueryResults = mainQuery
                .SetFirstResult((pagination.Page - 1)*pagination.PageSize).SetMaxResults(pagination.PageSize);

            var results = mainQueryResults.List<OrderDataDto>();
            return results;
```